# Display square in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Here is my question: Write an application that prompts the user to enter the size of the side of a square, then display a hollow square of that size made of asterisks. I have seen javascript using this but nothing with Visual Basic. Do they run hand and hand or does anyone know any good websites that could help me understand how to write this for Visual Basic.

Comment: to tell you the truth I am all confused with the visual basic. I understand something but to do this I have no clue where to start.

Comment: idont even know how to use the asterisk in visual basic

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a VB.NET introductory book.

Comment: I understand how to do dim and do the console.writeline stuff. A question do i put the * in or a number

Comment: i do know that three statements i am suppose to use in the for next loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an enjoyable diversion. :)

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("Enter square size:")
        Dim SquareSize As Integer = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine(StrDup(SquareSize, "*"))
        For x As Integer = 1 To SquareSize - 2
            Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("*", StrDup(SquareSize - 2, " "), "*"))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(StrDup(SquareSize, "*"))

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("DONE!")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```